# Apps not building nativescript for prd with webpack AOT

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I getting an error when I try to build an app for PRD with webpack and AOT activated.

If I disable AOT, the app build process is successful but then the app cannot be open (error saying app should close).
I could make it works disabling webpack, but I guess that's not how it should be...

For dev process I run the app with webpack with `tns run android` without issues.

The error I get when building with webpack and AOT is:

```
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI) ERROR in : TypeError: workaroundResolveModule.workaroundResolve is not a function
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI) ERROR in ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/mypath/src/app/routes/payment/payment.module.ngfactory.js' in '/mypath/$$_lazy_route_resource'
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI)  @ ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object ~/app/routes/payment/payment.module.ngfactory
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI)  @ ../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI)  @ ../platforms/android/app/snapshot-entry.js
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI) ERROR in ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/mypath/src/app/routes/user/user.module.ngfactory.js' in '/mypath/$$_lazy_route_resource'
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI)  @ ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object ~/app/routes/user/user.module.ngfactory
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI)  @ ../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
[19-07-08 10:57:31.698] (CLI)  @ ../platforms/android/app/snapshot-entry.js
[19-07-08 10:57:31.809] Build failed. Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.
```

Comment: Which version of NativeScript you are using?

Comment: The version is 5.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... after one day wasted in this, the solution was pretty simple...

Apparently, webpack is not loading static files that are not mention in the code or were forced to be loaded...

In order to load static files you need to add those in the `webpack.config.js` file.
I need to add this line to the `CopyWebpackPlugin`

```
{ from: { glob: "assets/i18n/*.json" } },
```

So the CopyWebpackPluging is:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "assets/i18n/*.json" } },
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

So when I run the app now I can see in the console the following line:

```
Successfully transferred en.json on device emulator-5554.
```

[Source](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-6.0-application-migration) (see Bundle workflow section)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by "fixing" versions matching for angular modules.

My project is at angular@7 but for some reason @angular/compiler-cli and @ngtools/webpack where at 8 in devDependencies.

> npm i @ngtools/webpack@^7.2.4 @angular/compiler-cli@^7.2.15

In my case, maybe you need other versions. 
Also, I needed to downgrade typescript@~3.1.1